# Can a MagicMock object be iterated over?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

What I would like to do is this...

```
x = MagicMock()
x.iter_values = [1, 2, 3]

for i in x:
    i.method()
```

I am trying to write a unit test for this function but I am unsure about how to go about mocking all of the methods called without calling some external resource...

```
def wiktionary_lookup(self):
    """Looks up the word in wiktionary with urllib2, only to be used for inputting data"""
    wiktionary_page = urllib2.urlopen(
        "http://%s.wiktionary.org/wiki/%s" % (self.language.wiktionary_prefix, self.name))
    wiktionary_page = fromstring(wiktionary_page.read())
    definitions = wiktionary_page.xpath("//h3/following-sibling::ol/li")
    print definitions.text_content()
    defs_list = []
    for i in definitions:
        print i
        i = i.text_content()
        i = i.split('\n')
        for j in i:
            # Takes out an annoying "[quotations]" in the end of the string, sometimes.
            j = re.sub(ur'\u2003\[quotations \u25bc\]', '', j)
            if len(j) > 0:
                defs_list.append(j)
    return defs_list
```

EDIT:

I may be misusing mocks, I am not sure. I am trying to unit-test this `wiktionary_lookup` method without calling external services...so I mock urlopen..I mock fromstring.xpath() but as far as I can see I need to also iterate through the return value of `xpath()` and call a method "`text_contents()`" so that is what I am trying to do here.

If I have totally misunderstood how to unittest this method then please tell me where I have gone wrong...

EDIT (adding current unittest code)

```
@patch("lang_api.models.urllib2.urlopen")
@patch("lang_api.models.fromstring")
def test_wiktionary_lookup_2(self, fromstring, urlopen):
    """Looking up a real word in wiktionary, should return a list"""
    fromstring().xpath.return_value = MagicMock(
        content=["test", "test"], return_value='test\ntest2')
    # A real word should give an output of definitions
    output = self.things.model['word'].wiktionary_lookup()
    self.assertEqual(len(output), 2)
```

Comment: What are you looking to mock exactly in your unittest? Also, your `MagicMock` example. What are you trying to do exactly with that list? I suspect you are misusing the mocks here. But I'm unsure what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @idjaw, added a response as an EDIT

Comment: Can you actually show your unittest code to see where suggestions could be provided for improvement?

Comment: @idjaw this is what I have so far. I just got into trying to iterate through the values in the MagicMock so it looks very incomplete right now

Comment: Better late than never. I don't know if you are still stuck on this, or figured out how to do it, but I wanted to share my solution. Hope this helps if you are still stuck. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually want to do is not return a `Mock` with a `return_value=[]`. You actually want to return a `list` of `Mock` objects. Here is a snippet of your test code with the correct components and a small example to show how to test one of the iterations in your loop:

```
@patch('d.fromstring')
@patch('d.urlopen')
def test_wiktionary(self, urlopen_mock, fromstring_mock):
    urlopen_mock.return_value = Mock()
    urlopen_mock.return_value.read.return_value = "some_string_of_stuff"

    mocked_xpath_results = [Mock()]
    fromstring_mock.return_value.xpath.return_value = mocked_xpath_results

    mocked_xpath_results[0].text_content.return_value = "some string"
```

So, to dissect the above code to explain what was done to correct your problem:

The first thing to help us with testing the code in the for loop is to create a list of mock objects per:

```
mocked_xpath_results = [Mock()]
```

Then, as you can see from

```
fromstring_mock.return_value.xpath.return_value = mocked_xpath_results
```

We are setting the `return_value` of the `xpath` call to our list of mocks per `mocked_xpath_results`.

As an example of how to do things inside your list, I added how to mock within the loop, which is shown with:

```
mocked_xpath_results[0].text_content.return_value = "some string"
```

In unittests (this might be a matter of opinion) I like to be explicit, so I'm accessing the list item explicitly and determining what should happen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up storing the response from the real wiktionary as a variable and then importing it and running a semi-real `fromstring` I will refactor with this when I have time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
mockToIterateThrough = MagicMock()
mockToIterateThrough.__iter__ = MagicMock(return_value=iter([1, 2, 3]))
```

[Source](https://programmaticallyspeaking.com/mocking-__iter__-with-a-magic-mock-in-python.html)